# rails form_tag url path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

This seems like it should be so simple but it has been causing me issues.

I have a select_tag that pulls from a model. All I want to is have a person choose their location from the drop down, press submit and take it to that places page.

Here is what I have

```
<% form_tag installation_path do %>
<%= select_tag :id, options_from_collection_for_select(Installation.find(:all), :id, :name) %>
<div id="button">
  <p>
    <%= submit_tag "Go", :name => nil %>
  </p>
</div>
```

The problem is it of course wants an `:id` but it won't pull the `:id` from the drop down menu below.

What am I doing wrong, any other suggestions on the "right" way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you actually want to GET, not to POST the params.

```
form_tag installation_path, :method => :get do
```

Comment: First off thanks! Using the wrong method was def one problem. However in order to have the routes correct it needs to be installation_path(id). However the id pulled is the id of the array from the collection_select. Any ideas? It really doesn't seem like this simple task should be so difficult.

Comment: Here's the thing, you want to submit the form, and go to `/installations/:id`. Instead you will end up in `/installations?id=:id`. So you could give Rails a route `match '/installations', :to => 'installations#show'`. The problem with that route is — it conflicts with index. So instead you should have a special route: `match '/goto_installation' => 'installations#show', :as => 'goto_installation'`. Then in your form: `form_tag goto_installation_path, :method => :get do`. Then in your controller's before filter you can `redirect_to installation_path(:id => params[:id])` to get the desired url.

Comment: Hi I am just getting back to this, it turns out I can not use "match" because I am not running rails3 yet. Any ideas on how else to do this. I just can't understand why this is so complicated. It seems like this is done all the time yet I can't seem to find any guidance. Thanks in advance. I appreciate your help.