# Devise ActionController::UrlGenerationError when trying to load form_tag and controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am adding devise to my Rails 5 app and when I go to `/users/sign_in` I get this error:

`No route matches {:action=>"email_signup", :controller=>"devise/jobs"}`

The error is here:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "jobs", action: "email_signup"}, method: "post") do %>
            <%= text_field_tag(:email_address, nil, placeholder: 'Email Address') %>
            <p><div class="button-wrap"><button data-dialog="maildialog" class="mailtrigger">Sign Me Up</button></div></p>
          <% end %>
```

Seems like devise is trying to look for the route in the context of devises own route. What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me out: [rails form_tag url path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176403/rails-form-tag-url-path)

I changed the form_tag to use the route rather than specifying the controller and that fixed the issue:

```
<%= form_tag(email_signup_jobs_path, method: "post") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:email_address, nil, placeholder: 'Email Address') %>
    <p><div class="button-wrap"><button data-dialog="maildialog" class="mailtrigger">Sign Me Up</button></div></p>
<% end %>
```